# Conjecture regarding trapping rational numbers in some special intervals

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, conjectures

### Conjecture:

Let $b\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq3}$ and $\{x_i\}$ be a collection of $b−2$ rational numbers greater than $1$. Does there always exist a natural number $a$ such that for all $i$ there exists some natural number $1\leq c\leq a$ such that:

$$\displaystyle \frac{ab-1}{(c-1)b+1}\geq x_i \geq \frac{ab-1}{cb-1}\tag{1}$$

One may think of this as having a **UNION** of $a$ intervals $\left[\frac{ab-1}{cb-1},\frac{ab-1}{(c-1)b+1}\right]$  on the real line and proving that, for some $a$, these can trap any finite discrete set of rational numbers having cardinality $b-2$.

For example, Let's assume $b=10$, $x=\{\frac{12}{5},\frac{17}{5},\frac{59}{10},\frac{187}{20},15,21,\frac{67}{2},39 \}$, then $(1)$ is true for $a=4$ and $a=5$ and therefore the intervals for $a=4,5$ contain or "trap" all the members of set $x$. In the diagram, the red/green regions are intervals $\left[\frac{ab-1}{cb-1},\frac{ab-1}{(c-1)b+1}\right]$ for all $c<a$.

[image]
What mathematical tools can one employ to tackle this?

**WHAT I DID:**

I solved the inequality $(1)$ for $a$ and got

$$\large x_i\left(1-\frac{2}{b}\right)+\frac{x_i+1}{b}+cx_i\geq a\geq \frac{x_i+1}{b}+cx_i\tag{2}$$

Note that $\frac{x_i+1}{b}+cx_i$ is common on both sides of the inequality.

Now I'll just have to plug in the values of $x_i$ to get $b-2$ inequalities and check for a common value of $a$ for any $c$.

For example, Let $x_i \in \{  \frac{101}{4},\frac{3001}{7} \}$ and $b=4$

then we have inequalities

$\frac{307}{16}+\left(\frac{101}{4}\right)c_1\geq a\geq \frac{105}{16}+\left(\frac{101}{4}\right)c_1$

$\frac{911}{32}+\left(\frac{301}{8}\right)c_2\geq a\geq \frac{309}{32}+\left(\frac{301}{8}\right)c_2$

Put $c=2$ in the first inequality and $c=1$ in the second inequality to get a common $a=58$.

But how should one go about to prove that there will always be some value of $a$ which satisfies the above set of inequalities? I calculated numerically for some random $b$ and $x_i$ and always managed to get some $a$, i.e., there existed some $a$ which trapped random $x_i$ given some random $b$. A counterexample may prove the negative but I was unable to find any.

Comment: This is rather confusingly written. Why introduce $c_i=i$ instead of using $i$ directly? And why write "for any $i$" in words above the displayed equation and "$\forall j$" in symbols behind the equation?

Comment: @joriki Fixed..

Comment: What is the $j$ in $x_j$?

Comment: A dummy variable...

Comment: You begin with "let $a\in\mathbb{N}$" and even use $a$ in the definition of $c$. Then you ask to prove the existence of $a$ subject to some condition. Do you see how this is a problem? Can you try to clarify the posing of the question?

Comment: @alex.jordan Please refer to the diagram for this. For $a=1$ there is only one interval (the inequality $(1)$) since $1\leq c\leq a$ which implies $c=1$. For $a=2$, we have $2$ intervals as $c$ can take $2$ values, namely, $1$ and $2$ and hence the set of rational numbers should be contained within the two inequalities. Does this clarify anything?

Comment: If I understand you, I would write this as: Let $b\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq3}$ and $\{x_j\}$ be a collection of $b-2$ rational numbers greater than $1$. Prove that there exists natural numbers $a$ and $c$ with $c\leq a$ such that for all $j$, that $\frac{ab-1}{(c-1)b+1}\geq x_j\geq\frac{ab-1}{cb-1}$. Note that this does not introduce $a$ or $c$ until a request is made to prove their existence.

Comment: Could you edit the question so that it becomes more approachable?

Comment: OK, now I think you are actually asking a question about a union of intervals. Sorry man - it's your question - I'll let you wordsmith it.

Comment: Yes it is about a union of $a$ number of intervals.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks for the edit.

Comment: There is a separate $c$ for each $x_i$, correct? Then shouldn't $c$ be subscripted; i.e., $c_i$?

Comment: Yup... separate $c$s for each $x_i$ it is. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Last clarification: it seems clear that the $x_i$s are distinct. Yes?

Comment: They need not be distinct. But considering that they are distinct would prove the conjecture generally. So you can assume that they are distinct.

Comment: Ah, of course, that's true.

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem / how did it arise?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR If true this would be used as a lemma for proving the [Lonely Runner Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_runner_conjecture)

Comment: Ooh, then I expect this is as hard as the Lonely Runner Conjecture, which many people (including me) have spent enough time on to understand that it's probably a hard problem. :-)

Comment: I searched long and hard but I failed to get information on any problem of this nature. Does that mean this problem requires a totally new mathematical approach?

Comment: It is completely unclear whether you want (1) to be true for all $i$ or just one of the $x_i$. It would seem that you'd want all $i$ for the problem to make sense, but you don't state that, and why the number of $x_i$ would matter is unclear. (It is also unclear where $c$ comes in. Perhaps you mean for every $i$ there is a $c$ such that (1) is true?)

Comment: $(1)$ should be true for all $i$. and $c$ is different for every $i$. $c_i$ might be a better notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. I didn't get too far, but perhaps this will be of help.

First, since all of the relevant quantities are non-zero, let us define $y_i\triangleq 1/x_i$ and invert the inequality:
$$\frac{(c_i-1)b+1}{ab-1} \leq y_i \leq \frac{c_ib-1}{ab-1}$$
Note that each $y_i$ is a rational number between $0$ and $1$, exclusive. So define $y_i=p_i/q$, where $q$ is a *common* denominator across all $i=1,2,\dots,b-2$, and each $p_i\in\mathbb{N}$  is between $1$ and $q-1$, inclusive. So we have
$$\frac{(c_i-1)b+1}{ab-1} \leq \frac{p_i}{q} \leq \frac{c_ib-1}{ab-1}$$
$$q((c_i-1)b+1) \leq p_i(ab-1) \leq q(c_ib-1)$$
$$q(1-b) \leq p_i(ab-1) - qc_ib \leq -q$$
$$q(1-b/2) \leq p_i(ab-1) - qc_ib + qb/2 \leq q(b/2-1)$$
$$\left| 2(ab-1)p_i - 2qb(c_i-1/2) \right| \leq q(b-2)$$
Here's the geometrical interpretation of this expression. The quantity $2qb(c_i-1/2)$ represents a finite grid $$\{qb,3qb,5qb,..,2qba-qb\}.$$ The quantity $2(ab-1)p_i$, on the other hand, represents the $b-2$ chosen points, which must lie on a different finite grid
$$\{2(ab-1),4(ab-1),\dots,2(q-1)(ab-1)\}.$$
So the challenge is to find a way to ensure that $b-2$ points selected from this second grid lie within $q(b-2)$ of the points from the first grid. Note that this is not trivially satisfied because this distance $q(b-2)$ is strictly less than half the spacing between the $c_i$ grid points. So there are indeed spaces that must be avoided when choosing $a$.

Comment: I certainly like your thoughts over this. Also should $a\leq q$ as it follows that $q$ is the period of required $a$s, i.e., suppose if $q=10, b=14$ and for some $p_i$, the value of $a$ less than $10$ is $3$, then in general $a=3+10n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Of course, $q$ is something determined by the set of $x_i$'s chosen, so in that case it is fixed, whereas $a$ is under your control.

Comment: So we need to find some $a$ in the region $\left[1,q\right]$. Does that reduce some non-triviality?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. But keep in mind that in order to avoid duplicate values of $x_i$, you must have $q-1\geq b-2$. After all, the only valid values of $p_i$ are $1,2,\dots,q-1$. So $q=10,b=14$ might not make a lot of sense to consider.

Comment: Oh... in that case just consider something like $q=15, b=14$ but I think you got the idea.

Comment: Also, $a\leq q$ implies $c_i< p_i$, i.e., $c_i$ can run through $1$ to $(p_i-1)$.

Comment: Cool. Well I likely won't be working on this anymore. Best of luck on this!

Comment: I found a counter-example using your reasoning. There exists no $a$ for $b=12$ and $x=\{12,\frac{12}{2},\frac{12}{3},\frac{12}{5},\frac{12}{6},\frac{12}{7},\frac{12}{8},\frac{12}{9},\frac{12}{10},\frac{12}{11}\}$

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I was not expecting it, given that I didn't finish the job :P

Comment: You were awarded the bounty because it was because of your reasoning I found a counterexample of the conjecture...